# Getting LaTeX with custom *.sty files rendered in an HTML document

Tags: packages, html, svg, latex2html

I've got a number of equations in a LaTeX document written in display mode. I'm using a *.sty file to be able to typeset them (inference rules).

I want to get *.svg versions of these into an HTML document programmatically.

Is there some way to either:

1. generate *.svg files per equation in display mode? or
2. add custom *.sty files (in my case for inference rules) to something like MathJax so I can write my LaTeX inference rules in an HTML document?

Comment: Depending on your use case, https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX may be a better choice. But it's definitely _not_ TeX.

Comment: you can add simple \newcommand and \def to mathjax but as you have given no example code its inpossible to say whether mathjax would understand the definitions you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tex4ht` for that. You didn't provide a sample file, but generally, you will need simple configuration file to request math to be converted as image and to declare image output format to SVG.

Save the following file as `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-align,pic-m+,pic-array,pic-cases,pic-eqalign,pic-eqnarray,pic-matrix}
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Your document can be then compiled using

```
make4ht -uc mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

You should get HTML file with all math content as SVG images.